# 'Controller' defining separately returns is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Don't know why this is not working this time..Previously every where its working bt this time its creating issues like this..

here i've like **app.js**

```
var testApp= angular.module('test',[]);

testApp.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.testValue='testttttttttt';
})
```

view file **index.html**

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
{{testValue}}
</div>
```

it working **fine**..

**but** when i make controller file seprately and call it in view

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    {{testValue}}
    </div>
<script src="testCtrl.js"></script>
```

*it returns its not function, undefined*...

but if in **app.js** 
i convert

```
var testApp= angular.module('test',[]);
```

to

```
var testApp= angular.module('test');
```

it works again..

here, whats the main problem?? like this i can't pass any dependecies.. Any suggestions please..

Comment: Can you share your code of controller in separate file ?

Comment: Also, it's important to note that `var testApp = angular.module('test')` is __not__ the same as `var testApp = angular.module('test', [])`. One is declaring a new module, the other is retrieving a preexisting one. If you use the second format in both files, then you'll just recreate your module. Wiping out anything you've previously added to it.

Comment: @suzo i ve been testing just as same testing controller for now .. its not working too..

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring and redeclaring a global variable for your module. This global variable will probably be hoisted or some other kind of javascript execution voodoo that will make your code behave in an unpredictable manner. To protect from this, just use angular's built in module `getter` call instead of declaring it on the global namespace.

Like so:

App.js

```
angular.module('testApp', [
    // dependencies here'
]);
```

TestCtrl.js

```
angular.module('testApp')
    .controller(function($scope) {
        $scope.testValue = "value";
    });
```

Again, the important distinction here is that `angular.module('testApp', [])` with the second argument (the dependency list) **creates** a new module, overwriting whatever `testApp` was before. On the other hand, `angular.module('testApp')` called without the second argument simply **retrieves** the module so that you can add more directives/controllers/config/constants to it.

Also, you should probably ditch stand alone controller, as they're not really considered best practice anymore. The directive/component route is much more *in vogue* right now.

For a brief overview of current angular best practices, check out John Papa's https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Place the controller file after loading the  app.js file.

So the content of the app.js will be,

```
var testApp= angular.module('test',[]);
```

Controller.js will be,

```
angular.module('test').controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.testValue='testttttttttt';
})
```

In index.html , order will be,

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="testCtrl.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/AFBcBmfz55Ug50KmREVA?p=preview)**

Comment: Probably because `testApp` being a global variable is generally considered bad form. It's better to use angular's intended getter method `angular.module('testApp')` to retrieve a module you want to add to.

Comment: if i ve not place that testctrl.js after app.js then it should not work in both case.. @sajee

Comment: @AaronPool it stills even not entering inside controllers . dont know why m getting this error :(

Comment: @BijayRai did you check the demo

Comment: Posted my own answer.